# SQL - reverse like. Is it possible?

Tags: sql

I have a db table containing these data

```
| id |  curse_word   | 
----------------------
| 1  |    d*mn       |
| 2  |    sh*t       |
| 3  |    as*h*le    |
```

I am creating this website that sort of behaves like an online forum where people can created discussion threads and talk about it. To be able to post you need to register. To register to need a forum username. We wanted to prevent usernames from containing curse words anywhere in it. These curse words are defined in our database.

To check for this using the table above, I have thought of using an sql query with like.

But what if the username registered is something like this -> "somesh*ttyperson". Since there is the word sh*t in it, the username should not be allowed. So this is something like using a sql query with reverse like.

I tried the following command below but it won't work:

```
select * from table where "somesh*ttyperson" LIKE curse_word
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you checked out `LIKE` operator? (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: @JagrutSharma what i need is something kind of a reverse like. to check if a reserved word is somewhere in the string of the input. not the other way around

Comment: One way is to create a `Set` of all these patterns in memory and compare incoming input with each item in the set. You will need to have a good way to keep it consistent with the table in db, possibly via some messaging mechanism.

Comment: Depending upon the language, you may be able to find a way to compile and match regex patterns. One reference for Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @JagrutSharma yes its possible to do it in java but my question is, is where a way to do this via sql? handle it all in the sql query

Comment: Possibly via a SQL stored proc

Comment: How about `CONTAINS("somesh*ttyperson", curse_word)` ?

Comment: Are you actually going to store the censored words, including `*`?

Comment: @GigiSan can you write the whole statement?

Comment: Here's some good introductory reading to the issue you're about to create for your users. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: @XmusJacksonFlaxonWaxon sorry, `CONTAINS` isn't suited for this. But I'm writing a new answer that might help you.

Comment: I wonder if there is a better way to deal with this?  some languages and name may legitimately include curse words.  Would you consider starting with site T&C's and manual moderation to test/pilot before you implement the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd give [Tomalak's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217881/sql-reverse-like-is-it-possible/71218716#comment125886530_71217881) some consideration, here's a solution that might fit your needs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM curse_words
WHERE "somesh*ttyperson" LIKE CONCAT('%', curse_word, '%');
```

In this way you are actually composing a `LIKE` comparison term for each of the curse words by prepending and appending a `%` (e.g. `%sh*t%`).

`LIKE` might be a bit expensive to query if you plan on having millions of curse words but I think it's reasonable to assume you aren't.

All you have to do now is test for this result being strictly equal to `0` to let the nickname through, or forbid it otherwise.

Comment: You can also avoid the `CONCAT` if you already insert the curse words with the `%` prefix and suffix.